# Regex containing (or not) whole words

Tags: regex

I would like to have a regex matching "house", "black house"... (* house), but not "white house".

> \b^(white)\b* house

That was one of my tries, but it does not match what I need. Any ideas?? Thanks!

Comment: What programming language (or editor) are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your language supports it you want to use [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
.*(?<!white\s)\bhouse\b
```

See a [live demo here](http://rubular.com/r/K9mstlsMRV).

Comment: This page contains many examples and useful information. Thank you very much!